# How to get Count and Sum based on ID

Tags: sql-server, datetime, join, count, average

I have a following table called lobby

```
QueueID FkBranch    IsActive    Status  AddedLocalTime          CompletedTime           FkAssistTypeID
553279  16              1           5   7/12/2019 20:06         7/12/2019  21:10                2
553278  16              1           5   7/12/2019 20:07         7/12/2019  21:11                1
553277  16              1           5   7/12/2019 20:08         7/12/2019  21:10                1
553276  16              1           5   7/12/2019 20:09         7/12/2019  21:11            1
553275  16              1           5   7/13/2019 20:10         7/13/2019  21:10            2
553274  16              1           5   7/13/2019 20:11         7/13/2019  21:11            2
553278  17              1           5   7/14/2019 20:07         7/14/2019  21:11                1
553277  17              1           5   7/14/2019 20:08         7/14/2019  21:10                1
553276  18              1           5   7/14/2019 20:09         7/14/2019  21:11            2
553275  18              1           5   7/15/2019 20:10         7/15/2019  21:10            2
553274  18              1           5   7/15/2019 20:11         7/15/2019  21:11            2
```

And Branch table and Its data as follows

```
BranchID    BranchName IsActive
16          Delhi        1
17          Karnataka    1
18          Telangana    1
```

Now I need to get a count of `FkAssistTypeID` of each location between `AddedLocalTime` and also need to take summation of the time difference of `AddedLocalTime` and  `CompletedTime`.

I have a function to get the time Difference of two dates and it as follows

```
dbo.fnTimetoSeconds(AddedLocalTime, CompletedTime, NULL)
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTimetoSeconds]
(
    @dateOne DATETIME,@dateTwo DATETIME,@dateToConvert DATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @date DATETIME
    DECLARE @retValue INT
    IF(@dateToConvert IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @dateToConvert = CASE WHEN(@dateTwo>@dateOne) THEN @dateTwo-@dateOne ELSE @dateOne-@dateTwo END
    END
    SET @date = DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, @dateToConvert))
    IF(DATEPART(yy,@dateToConvert) = 1900)
    BEGIN
        SET @retValue = DATEDIFF(s,@date,@dateToConvert) + CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(D, 0, @dateToConvert) > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(D, 0, @dateToConvert) ELSE 0 END * 3600 * 24
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @retValue = DATEDIFF(s,@date,@dateToConvert)
    END
    RETURN @retValue
END
```

My expected output is,
* Please be noted, This Average column need to calculate, Suppose

when `FkAssistTypeID = 1` and `AddedLocalTime` between 7/12/2019 and 7/14/2019 then by passing that row's `AddedLocalTime` and `CompletedTime` values `fnTimetoSeconds` taking time differance and take the summation of each time diffrences and divide it by count .

[image]

I need to add the above output to a temporary table. How can I do this?

I just tried this, but this is not the expected

```
select 
  b.BranchId AS ID, 
  b.BranchName,
  count(case l.FkAssistTypeId when 1 then 1 end) as CountOf1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (l.FkAssistTypeId = 1) THEN COALESCE((dbo.fnTimetoSeconds(CompletedTime, AssistedTime, NULL)),0) ELSE 0 END) AS Average 
from Branch b left join Lobby l
on b.BranchId = l.FkBranchId
where l.IsActive = 1 AND b.IsTestBranch = 0 AND CAST(l.AddedLocalTime as DATE) = '2019-07-12'
group by b.BranchId, b.BranchName
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this :

```
SELECT Vals.ID, 
       Vals.BranchName , 
       Vals.CountOf1, 
       CASE WHEN (Vals.CountOf1 = 0) THEN 0 ELSE Vals.mySum/Vals.CountOf1 END as AveSecs
INTO tmpTbl 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    b.BranchId AS ID, 
    b.BranchName,
    count(l.FkAssistTypeI) as CountOf1,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(second, CompletedTime, AssistedTime)) AS mySum 
  FROM Branch b 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Lobby l
  ON b.BranchId = l.FkBranchId
  WHERE l.IsActive = 1 
  AND b.IsTestBranch = 0 
  AND l.FkAssistTypeI = 1 
  AND l.AddedLocalTime >= '2019/07/12'
  AND l.AddedLocalTime < DATEADD(day, 1, '2019/07/15')
  GROUP BY b.BranchId, b.BranchName) as Vals
```

The query first gets the count and the sum between 2019/07/12 00:00 and 2019/07/15 00:00 (not including). Then it inserts into a temp table (as you indicated) while calculating the average value. Note that you will need to test it and adjust it a bit since I have not run it. Also, I just used date diff to calculate the time in seconds, but you can use your function if needed. They should come up with the same value most times.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you use the scalar function to get the date difference, even with the current logic, it's possible to do it in the query without the need of the function.

```
SELECT 
    b.BranchID
,   b.BranchName
,   ISNULL(l.CountOF1,0) CountOF1
,   ISNULL(l.Average ,0) Average 
FROM 
    @Branch b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      FkBranch
    , IsActive
    , COUNT(*) CountOF1
    , AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, AddedLocalTime, CompletedTime)) Average 
    FROM @lobby l
    WHERE 
        FkAssistTypeID = 1
    AND AddedLocalTime BETWEEN '7/12/2019 00:00:00' AND '7/14/2019 23:59:59'
    GROUP BY FkBranch, IsActive
) l ON l.FkBranch = b.BranchID AND l.IsActive = b.IsActive
WHERE 
    b.IsActive = 1
```

Comment: I also need to only check where `IsActive =1` in both tables. where I apply it in your query